# Inverse of Guava HashBiMap that has multiple keys point to one value

Tags: java, guava, inverse

I'm using a HashMap to associate multiple player objects with a single game object.

I want to be able to get the players associated to a certain game.
Therefore, I thought to use Guava's HashBiMap with players as keys, and games as values, and then take the inverse to find players associated to games.

Does anyone know if this is possible? The inverse returns another HashBiMap and because of the duplicate keys, I would really need a multimap.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CQEngine](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine):

```
IndexedCollection<GamePlayer> gamePlayers = new ConcurrentIndexedCollection<>();
SimpleAttribute<GamePlayer, Game> gameAttribute = attribute(GamePlayer::getGame);
SimpleAttribute<GamePlayer, Player> playerAttribute = attribute(GamePlayer::getPlayer);
gamePlayers.addIndex(HashIndex.onAttribute(gameAttribute));
gamePlayers.addIndex(HashIndex.onAttribute(playerAttribute));

Game spades = new Game("Spades");
Game hearts = new Game("Hearts");
Game rummy = new Game("Rummy");
Player joe = new Player("Joe", 23);
Player mary = new Player("Mary", 24);
Player jane = new Player("Jane", 19);
Player charles = new Player("Charles", 56);
Player daniel = new Player("Daniel", 29);

gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(hearts, joe));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(hearts, mary));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(hearts, jane));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(hearts, charles));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(spades, charles));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(spades, jane));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(spades, daniel));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(spades, mary));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(rummy, charles));
gamePlayers.add(new GamePlayer(rummy, jane));

System.out.println("Spades' players:");
for (GamePlayer spadesGamePlayer : gamePlayers.retrieve(equal(gameAttribute, spades))) {
    Player player = spadesGamePlayer.getPlayer();
    System.out.println("  - " + player.getName() + " (age " + player.getAge() + ")");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Mary's games:");
for (GamePlayer maryGamePlayer : gamePlayers.retrieve(equal(playerAttribute, mary))) {
    Game game = maryGamePlayer.getGame();
    System.out.println("  - " + game.getName());
}
```

Output:

```
Spades' players:
  - Daniel (age 29)
  - Jane (age 19)
  - Mary (age 24)
  - Charles (age 56)

Mary's games:
  - Hearts
  - Spades
```

Comment: It would be nice if whoever marked my answer as not helpful could comment why.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use more than one data structure.

For looking up all players in a game:

```
Map<Game, Set<Player>> gamePlayers = new HashMap<>();
```

If you need to find the game a certain player is in, you can also have:

```
Map<Player, Game> playersGames = new HashMap<>();
```

So you'll have

```
public void addPlayerToGame(Player player, Game game) {
  gamePlayers.computeIfAbsent(game, () -> new TreeSet<>()).add(player);
  playersGames.put(player, game);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have players mapped to games in `Map` (not `BiMap`, since couple players can be in the same game), you can use Guava's [`Multimaps#forMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#forMap-java.util.Map-) view and [`Multimaps#invertFrom`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom-com.google.common.collect.Multimap-M-) to achieve what you want and have games with collection of players per game (note that `invertFrom` copies values, so if you update `playersGames`, `gamesPlayers` won't change):

```
static Map<Player, Game> playersGames;

static {
    final Game game1 = new Game();
    final Game game2 = new Game();
    final Game game3 = new Game();
    playersGames = ImmutableMap.of(
            new Player(), game1,
            new Player(), game1,
            new Player(), game2,
            new Player(), game2,
            new Player(), game3
    );
    // {Player1=game1, Player2=game1, Player3=game2, Player4=game2, Player5=game3}
}

static Multimap<Game, Player> gamePlayers = Multimaps.invertFrom(
        Multimaps.forMap(playersGames),
        ArrayListMultimap.create()); // or any other Multimap implementation
// {game2=[Player3, Player4], game3=[Player5], game1=[Player1, Player2]}
```